# Append difference of elements in tuples in list

Tags: python, list, tuples

If I have a list such as `[(10, 22), (12, 50), (13, 15)]` and would like to append the difference of these numbers so that the list would look like `[(12, 10, 22), (38, 12, 50), (2, 13, 15)]` how can I do this?

I have this line of code `newList = [[???]+list(tup) for tup in list]` but am not sure what to put where the question marks are to get what I want.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

tuples can't be modified (they are immutable).  So you will have to create new tuples.  It looks like you are prepending the difference rather than appending.

```
newList = [(b-a, a,b) for (a,b) in oldList]
```